# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: f is not a function. (In 'f()', 'f' is undefined)]

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, es6-promise

In my React Native app, I get

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: f is not a function. (In
> 'f()', 'f' is undefined)]

With the following piece of code:

**home.js:**

```
import { CreateDBandTable } from "../components/InitFunctions";
const Home = () => {

  const {
    createDBandTableAsync,
    errorCreateDBandTableAsync,
  } = CreateDBandTable();


  useEffect(() => {
    showTables();
    createDBandTableAsync()
      .then(
          console.log("createDBandTableAsyncdone");
       )
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      })
      .finally(
        showTables();
      );
  }, []);
  .... // More code
```

**InitFunctions.js**

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
import { useState } from "react";

export const CreateDBandTable = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const createDBandTableAsync = async () => {
    const db = SQLite.openDatabase("testDB.db"); // returns Database object

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Check if the items table exists if not create it
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS savedRuns (runId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, runName TEXT, groupId INT, startTime TEXT, stopTime TEXT, elapsedMilliseconds INT)",
          [],
          (txObj, { rows: { _array } }) => {
            console.log("Table savedRuns created :", _array);
            resolve("RESOLVE Table savedRuns created :", _array);
          },
          (txObj, queryError) => {
            console.log(
              `Error while executing SQL in createDBandTableAsync (create table savedRuns): ${queryError}`
            );
            setError(queryError);
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      });

      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups (groupId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, groupName TEXT)",
          [],
          (txObj, { rows: { _array } }) => {
            console.log("Table groups created :", _array);
            resolve("RESOLVE Table groups created :", _array);
          },
          (txObj, queryError) => {
            console.log(
              `Error while executing SQL in createDBandTableAsync (create table groups): ${queryError}`
            );
            setError(queryError);
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  };

  return {
    createDBandTableAsync,
    error,
  };
};
```

I've tried a few different things but I always get the same warning:

- When the code is correct (no error expected)
- When I deliberately introduce a typo in one of the query.

What am I doing wrong with the promise?

As requested, the `showTables` code, but don't think it's relevant:

```
const showTables = async () => {
    const db = SQLite.openDatabase("testDB.db"); // returns Database object

    try {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' ",
          [],
          (txObj, { rows: { _array } }) => {
            console.log("SHOW TABLES :", _array);
          },
          (txObj, error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return true;
          }
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`error while SHOW TABLES: ${e}`);
    }
  };
```

Comment: First code smell: `createDBandTableAsync` and `showTables` are both `async` functions but don't use `await` anywhere

Comment: It's weird to create two transactions in the same function. Why not create both tables in the same transaction?

Comment: `.then(
          console.log("createDBandTableAsyncdone"))` and `.finally(,
        showTables(),
      );` look like typos. And in both cases, you need to pass callback functions to the methods.

Comment: @Bergi the functions use `async`, see `const createDBandTableAsync = async` for example. Sure I can create both tables in the same transaction.

Comment: I fixed the typos which I introduced when simplifying my code for this post.

Comment: Creating both tables in the same transaction still shows the error. Note that the code works, the tables are created properly.